# Facebook Sign In Segue To Main ViewController With Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, authentication, segue

I am using Parse / Swift with a custom Facebook Log In button. It successfully loads and the user can log in, but when it successfully logs in, only a flash of the MainViewController shows and then it returns to the Log In Page.

How can I get it to either use a segue or go to the Main View Controller after successful Facebook sign in? What is the correct code for Swift 2?

Below is my code in my SignInViewController for my Facebook button:

```
 @IBAction func didTapFacebookConnect(sender: AnyObject) {
    let permissions = [ "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions,  block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
              print ("The user cancelled the Facebook; login.")
        }
    })
```

EDIT:

This is now my new code but still having the same issue where the new ViewController is popping up briefly but then returning to the Sign In page.

This is the error I am receiving .. Warning: Attempt to present UITabBarController: 0x7face0f619f0> on U****d.SignInViewController: 0x7face0d1c310 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

```
@IBAction func didTapFacebookConnect(sender: AnyObject) {
    let permissions = [ "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions,  block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbSignIn", sender: self)

        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")


            } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")

            }
        } else {
              print ("The user cancelled the Facebook; login.")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, if the user signs in successfully, you actually are calling the dismiss view controller function twice. I'm not sure about the storyboard flow of your view controllers but there's no evidence of a segue here.

```
dismissViewController(true,completion:nil)
```

However if you created a segue from your log in controller to the home screen of your app in your storboard, upon a successful sign up or login, you should call the following with the appropriate identifier.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("SEGUEIDENTIFIER",sender:nil)
```

Also, a tip would be you should check PFUser.currentUser() to see if there's a cached user instance so you can segue right away to the home view controller without requiring the user to sign in everytime.

Comment: added this...  performSegueWithIdentifier("goSignIn") but get an error saying ....cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type..... and so on

Comment: i updated the argument call for performSegueWithIdentifier. You have to pass in a sender parameter of nil for you case. Also, make sure you that you create a segue and give it an identifier otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: I have updated my code with the perform segue but the issue is still happening. The new ViewController pops up briefly but then it returns to the SignIn page.

Comment: This is the error I keep getting... Warning: Attempt to present <UITabBarController: 0x7face0f619f0> on <Unilad.SignInViewController: 0x7face0d1c310> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!